# Copying and then sorting a linked list

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list

I have a linked list of Nodes, each Node is defined as:

```
struct Node {
  char name[14];
  int counts[130];
  char gender;
  Node *nextPtr;
};
```

I am copying this linked list with the following code:

```
// Create a copy of the current list
  Node *tempPtr;
  while (headPtr != NULL) {
    tempPtr = new Node;
    tempPtr = headPtr;

    // Advance the list
    headPtr = headPtr->nextPtr;
  } // End while loop
```

I need to copy the list so that I can sort it, I do not want to sort the original list. The sorting will be descending based on a value at a certain position of the counts[] array. I am wondering is somebody could tell me, am I copying the list correctly? And if I can have some insight as to how to go about and sort this list. I have written this in Java with no problem, I apologize for knowing too little of the c programming language. Any input will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

My apologies, I am to write this in the c++ programming language. However, I am not allowed to use C++ classes. I can only use C++ I/O stream, reference parameters, and dynamic memory allocation.

My main goal here is to make a list of pointers to the existing nodes, and then sort it without copying the nodes or disturbing the original list.

Comment: Why would you write your own linked list class in either C++ or Java (or C, come to that)?

Comment: @unapersson: This is an assignment

Comment: @VanDarg Then tag it as "homework". Still a waste of time, IMHO, and you still need to state what language (C or C++) you are using.

Comment: You want to make a list of pointers to the nodes, then sort it, without copying the nodes or disturbing the original list, is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as `new` in C. Are you using a c++ compiler?

Ignoring that, the problem is you aren't copying anything, and in fact are creating a memory leak:

```
tempPtr = new Node;
tempPtr = headPtr;
```

You create a new node on the heap, assigning the pointer to `tempPtr` ... then reassign `tempPtr` to `headPtr`. You just lost that newly allocated `Node` (memory leak).

To make a copy of the list, you need to iterate through your existing list, copying the data into new nodes that you're adding to a new list.

```
Node *oldNode = headPtr;
Node *newHead = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
Node *tail = newHead;

while(oldNode != NULL)
{
    memcpy(tail, oldNode, sizeof(struct Node));
    oldNode = oldNode->nextPtr;
    if (oldNode != NULL)
    {
        tail->nextPtr = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        tail = tail->nextPtr;
    }
}
```

(untested and I've not done C for a while but that should do it)

Comment: Yes, I am using a c++ compiler. Is there a way to make a list that has just references to existing Nodes?

Comment: @VanDarg: Then why tag the question `c`?

Comment: @VanDarg : The point is that the `c` tag is inappropriate since the code is not valid C. Pick a language.

Comment: @Brian Roach: Thank you, I will post back if I have problems

Comment: Fixed a couple dumb mistakes after reading back over it, I think that should work now.

Comment: Oops. Hmm, not really. I end up with an extra node on the end. **Editing**

Comment: @Brian Roach: This is great, I was able to copy the list, but how do I now reference the head of the new list?

Comment: via the new head ... `newHead`

Comment: @Brian Roach: Don't know how I missed that. Thank you so much for your help. I will now work on sorting.

Comment: this solution is in `C` though. And yet you have tagged the question as `C++`

Comment: @VanDarg: In C++, it is generally considered bad practice to use `malloc` and `free`.  You should use `new` and `delete` instead.  In C, `malloc` and `free` are fine.

Comment: @Brian @starcom - his original question was "How do I do this in C" .. it morphed into "No really, c++" but i'd already answered. You'll note the first sentence refers to this paradox as he had a `new` in his (supposed) C. If it had originally been c++ I prob would have just suggested adding a copy constructor and going that route.